# Python imports does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have such tree:

```
package/
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        impl/
            __init__.py
            moduleA.py
            moduleA_test.py
    subpackage2/
        __init__.py
        impl/
            __init__.py
            moduleB.py
```

In `moduleA.py` I have this code:

```
from subpackage2.impl.moduleB import func_abc
```

Module `moduleA_test.py` just imports `moduleA` and tests its functions.
When in terminal if I'm in folder `package` and run `python` and then `from subpackage1.impl import moduleA`, it works normally.

But if I run `python submodule1/impl/moduleA_test.py` (still in `package` folder) the code raises an error on the line of the import I wrote above. I get `ImportError: No module named subpackage2.impl.moduleB`.

I've also tried with `python -m submodule1.impl.moduleA_test.py` but with no luck.

Comment: From what directory are you running the code? If it's in `package`, then I don't think you should have any problems.

Comment: Python looks in the *current directory* by default - you will have to either append to `sys.path` or use the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html  6.1.2

Comment: Yes it is in `package`. I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

When you write `from subpackage2.impl.moduleB import func_abc`, it searches for the subpackage2 folder in the same directory as your code is i.e. package.subpackage1.impl.

So when you write the import statement it searches for package.subpackage1.impl.subpackage2.impl.moduleB which is not present and hence gives an error.